# how to join to crossrider API

Tags: crossrider

I read about crossrider API today and tried to find a page to signup or register in that as they said in http://www.crossrider.org/
but didnt find any page or any form for such action.
anyone knows about the problem?
many links that i found in the web about this was broken, even their [forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/crossrider/questions/)
that mentioned in FAQ page.
thanks for spending your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not Crossrider support. You may want to take a look at their contact form to ask this question.

Comment: Sorry guy, you are right. But I found just here as a community that members work with crossrider, and thought that you may help me.